# dexmaker gradle sync fails, and symbol not resolved

Tags: android

gradle sync keeps failing with my android studio. need help

https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker This is the open source i am trying to use called dexmaker. 
I tried to download by using

```
androidTestCompile 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline:2.21.0'
```

but it gets errors like this

```
Failed to resolve: com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline:2.21.1
```

I finally tried

```
androidTestCompile 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline:2.19.1'
```

this works but in my java code

The problem is even though i succeeded on syncing gradle, i still can't use the opensource.

```
 DexMaker dexMaker = new DexMaker();
```

DexMaker gets red lines and if i click it it says

```
cannot resolve symbol 'DexMaker'
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you using DexMaker in tests and not in your app code?

Comment: what do you mean in tests?

Comment: You add Dexmaker as test dependency: androidTestCompile. So that dependency is only available in tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but as I understand your situation:

You add dependency using androidTestCompile directive. That means that this package will become available only inside android test classes. For more understanding each dependency could be added in three ways: compile, testCompile and androidTestCompile.

- compile : Dependency is available everywhere in your application code.
- testCompile : Dependency available only in regular tests.
- androidTestCompile : Dependency available only in android tests.

So if you want that dependency to be available in your application - replace androidTestCompile with compile. But I not sure, that you SHOULD do that, cause that library is for tests.

P.S. Using compile directives is deprecated and you should use implementation, testImplementation and androidTestImplementation.

Comment: i think i understand a little i will try again